# multiple drop down boxes not picking up new elements (Selenium, C#)

Tags: c#, selenium

I have to drop down boxes I am trying to select using Selenium the first one works fine however when i try to select the second it does not pick up the values and still uses the first set of elements.

```
  public static void AnfoldComboBox(string sComboBoxId, string sItemText)
    {

        Drivers.CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"#{sComboBoxId} + .anfold-combobox .anfold-combobox-toggle.ui-corner-right")).Click();
        IWebElement dropDownWrapper = Drivers.CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("anfold-combobox-autocomplete"));
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> items = dropDownWrapper.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ui-menu-item > div"));

        foreach (IWebElement item in items)
        {
            if (item.Text.Trim() == sItemText)
            {
                item.Click();
                break;
            }  
        }
```

Comment: can you attach html with example

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code and check you are getting completer list from dropdown first ?

```
SelectElement test = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-menu-item > div")));
IList<IWebElement> size = test.Options;
int myitem = size.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < myitem; i++)
{
    String value = test.ElementAt(i).Text;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    if (val.Equals(sItemText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
    val.click();

    }
    else{
     Console.WriteLine("Not present");
    }
}
```